# How do I determine the schema elements for a valid XML document at the insert/cursor position?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have learned a lot from reading in this forum, but today I need to ask a question.

I am working on my own XML Author Editor, which will later be used to create instructions as XML documents. I am using AvalonEdit (C#/WPF) as the basis for the editor.

I already have an XML schema for validation. It is structured in such a way that each defined element (along with its attributes) is located at the top level directly under "xsd:schema" (see example).
Each of these elements has sub-elements that are included either as xsd:choice or xsd:sequence with "ref attributes". A referenced sub-element is always an upper level element.
This allows elements to be validly nested in the XML document while respecting the schema.

My question now would be:
Suppose the cursor is behind the element "`<emphasis>Text Emphasis</emphasis>`" in my XML document. How can I filter out the elements in the schema which can be validly inserted at the cursor position?

After all, it may be that some elements with the allowed number are already inserted, and thus only certain elements can be validly inserted.
My question is not only fixed on this example, but a general approach should be found.
I see the problem in the many possibilities XML Schema offers: Querying "complexType", "sequence", "minOccurs", maxOccurs" including their nestings seems to me a very big and error-prone effort.

Does anyone know an approach how I could proceed? Or can someone point me to projects or sites where I might find information?
XMetal, for example, provides a method "CanInsertList" in its paid XML editor API with the description "You can insert any element listed into the current selection".  I have tested this successfully with a trial version. So there must be a way.

XML-SCHEMA

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="paragraph">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">> 
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2">
                    <xsd:element ref="halfsided" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="emphasis" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="quotationmarks" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element  ref="numericallist" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element ref="info" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="creator" default="Employees1">
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="numericallist">
    ...
```

XML-Document

```
<section>
    <paragraph id="123">Text 1
        <emphasis>Text Emphasis</emphasis>
        <quotationmarks>Text Quotationmarks</quotationmarks>
        Text 2
    </paragraph>
</section>
```

Comment: The schema object model should help but as XSD schemas are complex this API for navigating them is also complex.

Answer (score 0):

You need access to a compiled form of the schema. For example, if you compiled the schema using Saxon-EE, you could export an SCM file containing the compiled schema, which includes an XML representation of the finite state automaton for validating complex types. With the FSA, you can determine what the valid transitions are from any given state, and you can use this for schema-aware editing.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thank you very much for your answer!

Michael, your suggestion to create a SCM file with Saxon-EE, which gives me useful data, sounds very good. There I also trust you without a doubt.

Unfortunately I don't have a Saxon-EE version yet to follow this. Of course I'm willing to invest in such a version if it helps me.

But I would like to have a look at a small Test.xsd with compiled Test.scm before, to see how I can build on it.
Is it possible to find such an example somewhere on the net, or could someone provide me with something like that?
That would be very helpful for sure.

Many greetings